# Using recursion in C++ class - Passing its own data member

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am writing a pre-order traversal for *Tree* class:

```
class Tree {
public:
  ...
  void preOrder(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if (root != nullptr)
        {
            cout << root->key << " ";
            preOrder(root->left);
            preOrder(root->right);
        }
    }
  
private:
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
}
```

I want to pass *Tree*'s *root* data member to *preOrder* so that in *main.cpp*, I call the function like this:

`Tree.preOrder();`

So I code like this

`void preOrder(TreeNode* root = this->root)`

but compiler generate error

> 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function

Is there anyway to fix this? Or I am going to use iterative instead of recursive traversal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error message says, you can't use `this` in a method parameter. Just define a 0-parameter overload of `preOrder()` that calls the 1-parameter version.

```cpp
class Tree {
public:
   ...

    void preOrder()
    {
        preOrder(root);
    }

    void preOrder(TreeNode* aRoot)
    {
        if (aRoot)
        {
            cout << aRoot->key << " ";
            preOrder(aRoot->left);
            preOrder(aRoot->right);
        }
    }
  
private:
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
};
```